# Bulk AD Users Creation

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-3.0

I am working on a PowerShell command where I have a `.csv` file with a certain attributes, but am actually stuck in completing it.

The attributes of my .csv file are in the following order:

- userPrincipalName
- sAMAccountName
- password
- givenName
- sn
- displayName
- description
- Path
- title
- company
- memberOf
- department
- mustChangePassword

My current code is this:

```
$Users = Import-Csv -Path "C:\BulkUsers.csv"            
foreach ($User in $Users)            
{      
    $UPN = $User.userPrincipalName
    $SAM = $User.sAMAccountName
    $Password = $User.password     
    $UserFirstname = $User.givenName            
    $UserLastname = $User.sn 
    $Displayname = $User.givenName + " " + $User.sn  
    $Description = $User.description  
    $Path = $User.Path            
    $Title = $User.title
    $Company = $User.company
    $Group = $User.memberOf
    $Department = $User.department          

    New-ADUser -UserPrincipalName $UPN -SamAccountName $SAM -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force) -GivenName "$UserFirstname" -Surname "$UserLastname" -DisplayName "$Displayname" -Description "$Description" -Path "$Path" -title "$Title" -company "$Company" -memberOf  "$Group" -department "$Department" -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
}
```

Am getting the below error while executing it:

```
New-ADUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'memberOf'.
At line:15 char:292
+ ... any "$Company" -memberOf  "$Group" -department "$Department" -ChangePasswordAtLo ...
+                    ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
```

Comment: Did you delete and reask this question? Did you see Ansgar's points about the last question. Your are not asking anything here. What is wrong with the code? Are you getting an error? You need to tell us what your problem is and your expected results.

Comment: Yes.. sorry i forgot to mention the error code, i have edited the post above, now can u help me ??

Comment: Instead of deleting and re-posting a question you should improve the question you already asked. Simply deleting questions when they contract downvotes is bound to lead to a [question ban](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/223370) sooner or later.

Comment: Well, thanks for highlighting that. Now well you be able to help on the above error for memberOf attribute error, my code works find if i delete that?? so where is the mistake?

Comment: Patience, young grasshopper. I was already working on that.

Comment: Alright :). waiting for your art of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty straightforward. If you take a look at the documentation for the [`New-ADUser`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617253.aspx) cmdlet you'll see that it doesn't have a parameter `-memberOf`. To add the newly created user to a group use the [`Add-ADGroupMember`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617210.aspx) cmdlet.

```
$Account = New-ADUser ... -PassThru
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Members $Account
```

This is assuming that the `memberOf` field from the CSV contains just a single group name or distinguished name.

The additional parameter `-PassThru` allows you to assign the created account object to a variable, so you can use that variable in the group assignment. Without that parameter `New-ADUser` runs silently (without output).

Comment: so in that case, how will i impelement that in my code? beside in my .csv file one user has multiple group

Comment: Well, where in your code do you have a `New-ADUser` statement? That's what you need to replace. If the user has multiple groups you need to add `Add-ADGroupMember` in a loop for all groups. However, since the groups come from a single CSV field you probably need to split that string to get an actual list.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I have done already that & it works like a charm.